# Access rightmost two columns of pandas dataframe, by number

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to overwrite some values in a `df` when a condition is met. Using the `df` below, when `col B` is equal to values in `lst`, I want to replace values in `col C,D` with `X`.

This can achieved using the method below but I'm hoping to use indexing to select the last two columns, rather than using hard coded labels.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'A' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],             
    'B' : ['X','Foo','X','Cat','A','A','X','D'],                 
    'C' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],    
    'D' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],            
    })

lst = ['Foo','Cat']
df.loc[df.B.isin(lst), ['C','D']] = 'X'
```

Attempt:

```
df.loc[df.B.isin(lst), df.loc[:-2]] = 'X'
```

Intended:

```
   A    B  C  D
0  1    X  1  1
1  1  Foo  X  X
2  1    X  1  1
3  1  Cat  X  X
4  1    A  1  1
5  1    A  1  1
6  1    X  1  1
7  1    D  1  1
```

Comment: The code already gives what you need. What are you looking for?

Comment: list(df.columns.values)[2:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question, it looks like you are searching for [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[df.B.isin(lst).values, -2:] = 'X'
```

In most cases, `df.loc[df.B.isin(lst), -2:] = 'X'` will also return the same result, but the interpretation of `-2:` slice will vary if the column names are of integer type.

Comment: I updated the answer. It turns out there are some differences with boolean arrays/Series depending on using loc or iloc. I think conceptually given that you want the last two columns (positional info) iloc should be used

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best attempt at a pandas-y approach, with the super-ugly and less performant `apply` method further down below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'A' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],             
    'B' : ['X','Foo','X','Cat','A','A','X','D'],                 
    'C' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],    
    'D' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],            
})

# get working index once,
# where column "B" in lst,
# store
ind = df["B"].isin(lst)

# get working slice with index
df_slice = df[ind]

# set the "C" and "D" columns
df_slice["C"], df_slice["D"] = "X", "X"

# set the original df slice
# to our working slice
df[df.B.isin(lst)] = df_slice

print(df)

### PRINTS:

   A    B  C  D
0  1    X  1  1
1  1  Foo  X  X
2  1    X  1  1
3  1  Cat  X  X
4  1    A  1  1
5  1    A  1  1
6  1    X  1  1
7  1    D  1  1
```

And here's the row-by-row `apply` approach. It's not the prettiest solution, but it gets the job done. Note that this just replaces the rest of the row with Xs.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'A' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],             
    'B' : ['X','Foo','X','Cat','A','A','X','D'],                 
    'C' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],    
    'D' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],            
})


def apply_function(row):
    lst = ['Foo','Cat']
    return row if row["B"] not in lst else [
        # first two rows
        *row[:2],
        # Xs for the rest of the row
        *["X" for r in range(len(row) - 2)]
    ]

df = df.apply(apply_function, axis=1)
print(df)

### PRINTS:

   A    B  C  D
0  1    X  1  1
1  1  Foo  X  X
2  1    X  1  1
3  1  Cat  X  X
4  1    A  1  1
5  1    A  1  1
6  1    X  1  1
7  1    D  1  1
```